# Dynamic search with request param

Tags: java, spring, request, repository

I created @Get endpoint to test dynamic search with request param.
My rest api is split into Controller -> Service -> Repository.

Enpoint in controller:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public Set<DriverDTO> test(@RequestParam(required = false)  String name,
                   @RequestParam(required = false)  String surname) {
    Set<DriverEntity> driverEntities = driverService.getAllTEST(name, surname);
    return modelMapperService.mapSetToSetOfEnteredClass(driverEntities, DriverDTO.class);
}
```

and my method in service prepared for test:

```
public Set<DriverEntity> getAllTEST(String name, String surname) {
    ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher
            .matchingAll()
            .withMatcher("name", contains().ignoreCase())
            .withMatcher("surname", contains().ignoreCase());

    DriverEntity example = DriverEntity
            .builder()
            .name(name)
            .surname(surname)
            .build();
    return new HashSet<>(driverEntityRepository.findAll(Example.of(example, matcher)));
}
```

I would like to create one endpoint with optional request parameteres for dynamic searching. I found solution like that and for expample for request like:

```
http://localhost:8081/drivers/test?name=tom&surname=smith
```

it works but is it the best way do it? Maybe there are any other and better solutions?

Comment: Depending on the amount of Parameters you have it would be beneficial to use a DTO in the http body (@RequestBody). Your parameteers there can be "null" by default.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to create one endpoint with optional parameters. For example I wanna have request which returns all of DTO's and request only with DTO's which contains for example specified name

Comment: You can still do that with a request DTO. The response DTO is independet from that.